# numpy.hstack alternative for numba.njit

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba

Hello fellow programmers!

I want to use this code but the `np.hstack` function does not seem to be compatible with `numba.njit` decorator:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.njit
def main():
    J_1 = np.array([[-64., 25.6, 25.6, 12.8], [25.6, -25.6, 0., 0.], [25.6, 0., -25.6, 0.], [12.8, 0., 0., -652.8]])
    J_2 = np.array([[-85.33333333, 34.13333333, 34.13333333, 17.06666667], [34.13333333, -34.13333333, 0., 0.], [34.13333333, 0., -34.13333333, 0.], [17.06666667, 0., 0., -870.4]])
    J_3 = np.array([[85.33333333, -34.13333333, -34.13333333, -17.06666667], [-34.13333333, 34.13333333, -0., -0.], [-34.13333333, -0., 34.13333333, -0.], [-17.06666667, -0., -0., 870.4]])
    J_4 = np.array([[-64., 25.6, 25.6, 12.8], [25.6, -25.6, 0., 0.], [25.6, 0., -25.6, 0.], [12.8, 0., 0., -652.8]])
    J_old = [[J_1, J_2], [J_3, J_4]]
    J_stack = np.hstack(J_old[0])
    for row in J_old[1:]:
        col = np.hstack(row)
        J = np.vstack((J_stack, col))

    print(J)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\python.exe C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 401, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 344, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\utils.py", line 80, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<function hstack at 0x000001981A60B558>) with argument(s) of type(s): (list(array(float64, 2d, C)))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    TypeError: np.hstack(): expecting a non-empty tuple of arrays, got list(array(float64, 2d, C))
    raised from C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typing\npydecl.py:779
In definition 1:
    TypeError: np.hstack(): expecting a non-empty tuple of arrays, got list(array(float64, 2d, C))
    raised from C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typing\npydecl.py:779
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: resolving callee type: Function(<function hstack at 0x000001981A60B558>)
[2] During: typing of call at C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py (11)


File "test2.py", line 11:
def main():
    <source elided>
    J_old = [[J_1, J_2], [J_3, J_4]]
    J_stack = np.hstack(J_old[0])
    ^


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Originally this snippet:

```
J_old = [[J_1, J_2], [J_3, J_4]]
J_stack = np.hstack(J_old[0])
for row in J_old[1:]:
    col = np.hstack(row)
    J = np.vstack((J_stack, col))
```

was a replacement of `J = np.bmat([[J_1, J_2], [J_3, J_4]])` which didn't work with the `numba.njit` decorator either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.hstack` is one of numba [supported numpy features](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html#other-functions), the error message clearly states something else. As a simple solution, you can use the following  one liner  after your four blocks assignment in order to construct `J` (tested on numba `0.48.0`):

```
J = np.vstack((np.hstack((J_1, J_2)),np.hstack((J_3, J_4))))
```

This gives a result equivalent to the output of `np.bmat`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message

```
TypeError: np.hstack(): expecting a non-empty tuple of arrays, got list(array(float64, 2d, C))
```

we see the problem: the Numba version of `hstack` expected a tuple of arrays, and you gave it a list of arrays. (The NumPy version of `hstack` is more tolerant and will let you use a list.)

This can be fixed by simply using tuples instead of lists inside your `J_old`:

```
J_old = [(J_1, J_2), (J_3, J_4)]
```

and more generally always using tuples when possible in Numba, since list support exists but is fairly incomplete and many of the functions aren't happy with lists even when it is technically possible (though not idiomatic) to use lists as arguments to NumPy.

(Of course, the solution by Yacola is far more of an improvement—I just wanted to point out that this is the minimal change needed for Numba to work.)